# way to get value for address in this case?

Tags: ios

```
{
  "status": "true",
  "message": "11 records found",
  "response": [
    {
      "name": "1",
      "address": "565400-",
      "phone": "",
      "gym_email": "",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "123",
      "address": "102-",
      "phone": "",
      "gym_email": "1@2.com",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "Burn Gym & Spa",
      "address": "Sector 11,HaryanaPanchkula-134101",
      "phone": "",
      "gym_email": "1@2.com",
      "images": "a:1:{i:0;s:18:\"1478177269200.jpeg\";}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Burn Gym",
      "address": "NAC,ManimajraChandigarhPanchkula-134112",
      "phone": "",
      "gym_email": null,
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "Burn Gym & Spa",
      "address": "Sector 11,ChandigarhAmbala-160101",
      "phone": "585888",
      "gym_email": "1@2.com",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "test gym",
      "address": "Sector 11,HaryanaPanchkula-134101",
      "phone": "0",
      "gym_email": "1@2.com",
      "images": "a:1:{i:1;s:17:\"1478579644341.png\";}"
    },
    {
      "name": "test gym",
      "address": "Sector 12HaryanaPanchkula-134101",
      "phone": "0",
      "gym_email": "",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "new gym",
      "address": "sector 11HaryanaPanchkula-134112",
      "phone": "789654123",
      "gym_email": "keshavkpnf@gmail.com",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "hrhrrth",
      "address": "sector 11HaryanaPanchkula-134101",
      "phone": "8054233444",
      "gym_email": "keshavkpnf@gmail.com",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "hrhrrth",
      "address": "sector 4HaryanaPanchkula-134101",
      "phone": "0",
      "gym_email": "",
      "images": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "hrhrrth",
      "address": "sector 11HaryanaPanchkula-134101",
      "phone": "8054233444",
      "gym_email": "keshavkpnf@gmail.com",
      "images": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what you have tried and in which variable this json is stored?

Comment: There are countless examples of parsing JSON data in an iOS app. Please do some basic research. Try something. Update your question with what you have tried and explain clearly what issue you are having.

Comment: i am having a table view and want to get the value of all address and then want to set this value for a particular cell of table view

Comment: mdict  variable @Ali

Comment: [[mdict valueForKey:@"response"]valueForKey:@"address"];

i have tried this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addressLabel.text=[[[mdict objectForKey:@"response"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"address"];

Comment: here "mdict" is the dictionary contains the entire data.    response is the array contains a field named  "address" and "indexpath.row" represent the cell index which the index for array also.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of address as:

```
guard let response = json["response"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else { 
  print("Nothing here") 
  return
}
```

then you can get address from the response array by looping,

```
for data in response {
  print(data["address"] as? String)
}
```

Comment: i am using objective c aakash

Comment: @DavenderVerma I am not much familiar with Objective C, you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311899/parse-json-using-objective-c

Comment: Similar type of json parsing is done in the above link, it may help

Answer (score 0):

```
if((jsonResult) != nil) {
    let swiftyJsonVar = jsonResult!
    do {
       if let dicObj = swiftyJsonVar as? NSDictionary {
           print("Response is dictionary")
           print(dicObj)
           let arrObj = dicObj["response"] as NSArray
            // Then iterate your arrObj and do as per your need.
            //for eg.
           arrObj[0]["address"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sarabjit i am using obj c

Comment: okay... i will change this code in objective c and share with you....

Comment: thx for support

Comment: NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];
 NSDictionary *dictionary = array[0];

 NSArray *arrRes = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"response"] objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
  For ( NSDictionary *dic in responseArray){
      NSDictionnary *response = [dic objectForKey@"address"];
 }